# Has the Mars dust storm affected its naked-eye appearance?

Tags: mars, dust-storm

Mars has been undergoing a planet-wide dust storm for a couple of months now.
[image]

By my eye, while Mars currently looks a bright and handsome orange, there's been no change that I've been able to notice from this dust storm. Is it possible for an experienced naked-eye (or small telescope) astronomer to have noticed the change in appearance brought on by this dust storm?

Comment: I've been observing Mars a couple of times this summer with my 6" telescope and I've seen a visual difference, now I can see a few surface features and the ice cap, but in June/July they were pretty much hidden beneath the storm, and the planet appeared uniform in color. With the naked eye only though, I haven't noticed any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible for an experienced naked-eye (or small telescope)
>   astronomer to have noticed the change in appearance brought on by this
>   dust storm?

Yes, it is definitely possible. Without dust storms it looks redder.

**Source:**

- [The opposition of Mars, 2001: Part I - Richard McKim](http://alpo-j.asahikawa-med.ac.jp/kk01/JBAA119123-143McKim.pdf)